# My Json Response result is not the same in the database query result

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

So when i get data by email and password ,i want to use native query as my query method but the response i get in the json is different in the database query result

here is my NativeQuery in my repository.java

```
public interface UsersRepository extends JpaRepository<Users, Long>{
    @Query(value="SELECT * "
            + "FROM USERS u " 
            + "JOIN HAK_AKSES h "
            + "ON (u.USER_ID = h.USER_ID) "
            + "JOIN ROLES r "
            + "ON (h.ROLE_ID = r.ROLE_ID) "
            + "JOIN ROLE_MENU rm "
            + "ON (r.ROLE_ID = rm.ROLE_ID) "
            + "JOIN MENU m "
            + "ON (rm.MENU_ID = m.MENU_ID) "
            + "WHERE u.EMAIL = :email AND u.PASSWORD = :password ", 
            nativeQuery = true)
    List<Users> getAll(@Param("email") String email, @Param("password") String password);
}
```

and here is my service

```
public class UsersService {
    @Autowired
    UsersRepository usersRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    HakAksesRepository hakAksesRepository;
    
    
    public List<UsersWrapper> getAll(String email, String password) {
        List<Users> loginList = usersRepository.getAll(email, password);
        return toWrapperList(loginList);
    }

    private UsersWrapper toWrapper(Users entity) {
        UsersWrapper wrapper = new UsersWrapper();
        wrapper.setUserId(entity.getUserId());
        wrapper.setUsername(entity.getUsername());
        wrapper.setPassword(entity.getPassword());
        wrapper.setNama(entity.getNama());
        wrapper.setAlamat(entity.getAlamat());
        wrapper.setEmail(entity.getEmail());
        wrapper.setTelp(entity.getTelp());
        wrapper.setProgramName(entity.getProgramName());
        wrapper.setCreatedDate(entity.getCreatedDate());
        wrapper.setCreatedBy(entity.getCreatedBy());
        wrapper.setUpdatedDate(entity.getUpdatedDate());
        wrapper.setUpdatedBy(entity.getUpdatedBy());
        wrapper.setHakAksesId(entity.getHakAksesId());
        return wrapper;
    }
    

    private List<UsersWrapper> toWrapperList(List<Users> entityList) {
        List<UsersWrapper> wrapperList = new ArrayList<UsersWrapper>();
        for (Users entity : entityList) {
            UsersWrapper wrapper = toWrapper(entity);
            wrapperList.add(wrapper);
        }
        return wrapperList;
    }
    


    private Users toEntity(UsersWrapper wrapper) {
        Users entity = new Users();
        if (wrapper.getUserId() != null) {
            entity = usersRepository.getReferenceById(wrapper.getUserId());
        }
        Optional<HakAkses> optionalHakAkses = hakAksesRepository.findById(wrapper.getUserId());
        HakAkses hakAkses = optionalHakAkses.isPresent() ? optionalHakAkses.get() : null;
        entity.setHakAksesId(hakAkses.getHakAksesId());
        entity.setUsername(wrapper.getUsername());
        entity.setPassword(wrapper.getPassword());
        entity.setNama(wrapper.getNama());
        entity.setAlamat(wrapper.getAlamat());
        entity.setEmail(wrapper.getEmail());
        entity.setTelp(wrapper.getTelp());
        entity.setProgramName(wrapper.getProgramName());
        entity.setCreatedDate(wrapper.getCreatedDate());
        entity.setCreatedBy(wrapper.getCreatedBy());
        entity.setUpdatedDate(wrapper.getUpdatedDate());
        entity.setUpdatedBy(wrapper.getUpdatedBy());
        return entity;
    }

}
```

```
here is the response i get in json
```

{
"status": true,
"message": null,
"timeStamp": 1671604833867,
"data": [
{
"userId": 1,
"username": "user1",
"password": "user1",
"nama": "User 1",
"alamat": "Jakarta",
"email": "user1@gmail.com",
"telp": "085729380129",
"programName": null,
"createdDate": "2022-12-20",
"createdBy": "user1",
"updatedDate": "2022-12-20",
"updatedBy": "user1",
"hakAksesId": 1
},
{
"userId": 1,
"username": "user1",
"password": "user1",
"nama": "User 1",
"alamat": "Jakarta",
"email": "user1@gmail.com",
"telp": "085729380129",
"programName": null,
"createdDate": "2022-12-20",
"createdBy": "user1",
"updatedDate": "2022-12-20",
"updatedBy": "user1",
"hakAksesId": 1
},
{
"userId": 1,
"username": "user1",
"password": "user1",
"nama": "User 1",
"alamat": "Jakarta",
"email": "user1@gmail.com",
"telp": "085729380129",
"programName": null,
"createdDate": "2022-12-20",
"createdBy": "user1",
"updatedDate": "2022-12-20",
"updatedBy": "user1",
"hakAksesId": 1
},
{
"userId": 1,
"username": "user1",
"password": "user1",
"nama": "User 1",
"alamat": "Jakarta",
"email": "user1@gmail.com",
"telp": "085729380129",
"programName": null,
"createdDate": "2022-12-20",
"createdBy": "user1",
"updatedDate": "2022-12-20",
"updatedBy": "user1",
"hakAksesId": 1
},
{
"userId": 1,
"username": "user1",
"password": "user1",
"nama": "User 1",
"alamat": "Jakarta",
"email": "user1@gmail.com",
"telp": "085729380129",
"programName": null,
"createdDate": "2022-12-20",
"createdBy": "user1",
"updatedDate": "2022-12-20",
"updatedBy": "user1",
"hakAksesId": 1
},
{
"userId": 1,
"username": "user1",
"password": "user1",
"nama": "User 1",
"alamat": "Jakarta",
"email": "user1@gmail.com",
"telp": "085729380129",
"programName": null,
"createdDate": "2022-12-20",
"createdBy": "user1",
"updatedDate": "2022-12-20",
"updatedBy": "user1",
"hakAksesId": 1
}
]
}

this is what the data look like
[query result in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZyfw.png)
so the column hakakses is not getting the other value

Comment: Please fix your code block formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You have use * in native query and in database you choose selected data

```
public interface UsersRepository extends JpaRepository<Users, Long>{
        @Query(value="SELECT u.UserId, "
                + "FROM USERS u " 
                + "JOIN HAK_AKSES h "
                + "ON (u.USER_ID = h.USER_ID) "
                + "JOIN ROLES r "
                + "ON (h.ROLE_ID = r.ROLE_ID) "
                + "JOIN ROLE_MENU rm "
                + "ON (r.ROLE_ID = rm.ROLE_ID) "
                + "JOIN MENU m "
                + "ON (rm.MENU_ID = m.MENU_ID) "
                + "WHERE u.EMAIL = :email AND u.PASSWORD = :password ", 
                nativeQuery = true)
        List<Users> getAll(@Param("email") String email, @Param("password") String password);
    }
```

Comment: I have added just u.UserId. You will add more according to your data